# SQL dynamic string filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the user to select which columns they want to see from a table and be able to get results even when they don't fill out someone's whole name (like a filter). When the code below is not in a SET string it does work fine but  when it is, I do have a bug I can't see. The error is on the 'WHERE' line, well that's what SQL server is telling me.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(Max) = ''
SET @SQL = 
'
    SELECT ' + @TableList + ' FROM People
    WHERE (IsNull(Input.Name, '''')  LIKE ''%''  '+ @Name +'  ''%'')
'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Below is what the query looks like when it's not in a string and does work normally.

```
    SELECT [Name], [Age], [City] FROM People
    WHERE (IsNull(Input.Name, '')  LIKE '%' + @Name + '%')
```

And let's say a user enters the name 'Tom', they will get the following results...

```
Name     Age      City
Tom      28        NY
Tommy    35        LA
```

The error message I am getting is...

```
The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator.
```

Which does confuse me a bit since it does work fine when it's not in a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many ' in your statement.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(Max) = ''
SET @SQL = 
'
    SELECT ' + @TableList + ' FROM People
    WHERE (IsNull(Input.Name, '''')  LIKE ''%'+ @Name +'%'')
'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it and I did have more then I should of had.